# Where can I find flight plan records for a private flight in the 1970s?

Tags: usa, flight-plans, canada

How would I find a record of a private plane flight from Canada to the US in the early to mid 1970's? I am researching records of my father.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the type of aircraft, but if any records have managed to not be destroyed after 48 years, I would suggest you start by talking to the owner/operator of the departure and arrival airfields. US Customs might have a record of a customs inspection if there was one, but you'd have to file a FOIA request and be prepared to wait for an answer which may not be the one you want to hear.